How to factory reset a Mac desktop running El Capitan?
I've never posted here before, but I'm having an issue with a Mac my boss needs me to reset. Ideally, she wants it to continue running El Capitan, as she's worried updating the OS with cause more issues.
I've looked into some other forum posts, but I'm not sure I'm interpreting the instructions correctly. Do I have to have access to a copy of the current OS in order to re-install/ reset things? Will updating to a newer macOS cause any issues?

What model/year is the Mac?

This may help: Reset El Capitan and Kappy's response at Apple Community.

By reset do you mean destroy all data and put it into the sat if just received from Apple?

I'm having an issue with a Mac that my boss needs me to reset.
"Nuke and pave" (erasing everything and reinstalling the OS) is a fairly drastic solution to any given problem; though a brand new system volume should fix any problem (excluding bugs in the OS and hardware faults).
Ultimately, any benefits from the process come from the deletion of user settings (plists, databases, caches, etc) and third-party software.
Of course, if you restore all the user data from a TM backup after erase-and-install, then you're back where you started!
Ideally, it would be useful to know what the problem is, and whether there's a more focused approach that might fix it.
Usual tests include running a brand new user account, which will pinpoint whether the problem is caused by something in the original user account, or if it is system-wide; and running in Safe Boot mode, which will pinpoint whether the problem is caused by third-party system extensions.
Will updating to a newer macOS cause any issues?
The assumption that newer OSes will exacerbate matters needs to be challenged. Every OS fixes some bugs and introduces others, of course; but by the end of the annual cycle, most OSes are stable. There is no evidence to suggest that things are continually getting worse, or that old machines can't cope with newer OSes.
If Apple thought that the performance of an old Mac on a new OS wasn't good enough, that would be a criterion for excluding it from the list of supported models.
Of course, apps might need updating for newer OS versions; but any environment with a "boss" ought to be using software that is still being developed, for which there are newer, supported versions.

What if there is a Core Storage Fusion Drive? What if there are 32 bit applications?

@DavidAnderson Are you saying that older Fusion Drives don't work on newer OSes? I'll add a bit about the inevitability of updating apps.

After some additional testing (in a virtual machine), I see erasing OS X or upgrading to a macOS version is not a problem when a Mac is using a Fusion Drive (assuming the partitioning is OK). I should not have included a question regarding a Fusion Drive in my previous comment.

@DavidAnderson Fusion Drives were (sadly!) still being sold in 2019 iMacs, and Apple hasn't issued any special advice about upgrading the OS on those Macs.

Please back up all data before proceeding.
A network connection will be required in Recovery Mode.

Restart the computer, then enter Recovery Mode Cmd-R.
Select Disk Utility from the top left menu and click Continue.
Select volume, Macintosh HD.
Click on the erase icon in Disk Utility.
Set the format type, Mac OS Extended (Journaled).
Click Apply and then wait for the Done button to activate and then click Done.
Quit Disk Utility and return to the main menu.
Select Reinstall OS X and click Continue.

Source: Wipe and reinstall OS X El Capitan
